# Gradle import for org.apache.commons.id

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to use [this](https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/apidocs/org/apache/commons/id/uuid/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromString(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.id.uuid.UUID)) library in my code. But I'm having a hard time understanding how to import it to my build.gradle file. Where can I locate what gradle import to add? I can't seem this find this library in mvnrepository.